# Why less files changes applies after deleting pub folder Magento 2?

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, less, magento2

Hi I am building a new theme in Magento 2 and extended a theme from the luma.

But when I am doing any changes in the less files to customize the
look I need to delete the pub folder file every-time after making
change in a less css file.

Is there any setting (in less) or way that I can automatically synchronize file changes?

Comment: Grunt commad working on your system ?

Comment: sorry i have no idea abut grunt can you please provide more information.

Comment: have you installed node.js ?

Comment: you can install node.js via : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: removed thanks comments and rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options available, one is to use grunt for server side compilation and another is to use less.js for client side (browser) compilation.

Using client side should be easier to setup, but using Grunt might be more performant for you.  To keep things simple I'll only talk about using client side.

These instructions are just copied from the dev docs, references at the bottom of the post.

> 1. In the Magento Admin, change the LESS compilation mode to client-side under **STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow > Workflow type**.
> 2. Delete all files in the following directories:
>
>    - `pub/static/frontend/<Your_Vendor>/<your_theme>`
>    - `var/view_preprocessed/less`

After performing those steps you should be able to just refresh the page after making changes to your .less files.

References:

- [Using server side w/ Grunt](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html##server-side-grunt)
- [Using client side](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html#client-side)
- [Preprocessing modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#less_modes)

Comment: it seems interesting.I have not try this yet but will do it soon.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can use local node.js to automate this processes

make sure that you have node.js installed locally

do in project folder cmd "npm install" to upload node packages

and you are ready to go, use:

grunt refresh (to start or when you add/remove less files);

grunt less (to compile all less files);

grunt watch (to watch changes in less files and compile them automatically);

grunt clean (to delete all temporary files)

Comment: thanks for the information let me try your sugestions

Comment: You are success or not ?